# How can I configure JUnit to ignore @Before and @After annotations

Tags: junit, junit4

We have many test classes that are annotated with @Before and @After to perform test construction/destruction.

But because we now need to perform actions on test failure but prior to @After executing we have used a RuleChain to handle test construction / destruction ourselves. It just points back to the setUp() and tearDown() methods (yes we were lucky that most developers had stuck to that convention).

The problem is that JUnit still invokes the methods annotated with @Before and @After as well as invoking them via the new Rule.

At it's core JUnit is invoking

```
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate
```

for the innermost statement.

One option is obviously removing the @Before and @After annotations from the Tests, but we are talking about many hundreds of tests.

How can we switch off processing of @Before and @After ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can flick a JUnit 'switch' to disable this behaviour. JUnit offers two ways of changing test execution behaviour:

- Extend `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`
- Add a `Rule` to your test case

Both of these require you to change your test cases, of these the second option might be least invasive (though that does depend on whether your test cases are already using customised runners).

Given this simple JUnit runner:

```
public class IgnoreBeforeAndAfter extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public IgnoreBeforeAndAfter(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    protected Statement withBefores(FrameworkMethod method, Object target,
                                    Statement statement) {
        return statement;
    }

    protected Statement withAfters(FrameworkMethod method, Object target,
                                   Statement statement) {
        return statement;
    }
}
```

The following test case will pass (thereby proving that the `@Before` and `@After` methods are not invoked):

```
@RunWith(IgnoreBeforeAndAfter.class)
public class SimpleTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Assert.fail("The @Before method should be ignored!");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        Assert.fail("The @After method should be ignored!");
    }

    @Test
    public void canIgnoreBeforeAndAfter() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

A structural search+replace on your code base could be used to add this annotation to all test cases which contain at least one of `@Before` or `@After`.

Though of course a structural search+replace could also remove all `@Before` and `@After` annotations from your code.

An approach which requires no changes to your existing test cases (but which is somewhat non standard) would be to provide no-op implementations of ...

- `org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters`
- `org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores`

... in your own code base, these would 'replace' the JUnit equivalents and if their `evaluate()` method body was empty then your use of the `@Before` and `@After` annotations would have no effect.

Comment: Thanks. Using RunWith looks like a great solution. unfortunately our test classes are already annotated with @RunWith to use a 2rd party Runner that extends from TestSuite instead of BlockJUnit4ClassRunner, so I'm not going to be able to use it. But by defining a TestRule annotation with TestClass and using TestClass to find the Before and After annotations I can at least log or fail if I discover Before/After annotations that will wreck us. It's a shame that the capabilities of BlockJUnit4ClassRunner aren't exposed at a higher level.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to inject all behaviour such as BeforeClass, Before, AfterClass, After into the Runner using Annotations.

Comment: Yeah, the way the hooks are implemented works fine for simple cases but cherry picking your test execution flow becomes more difficult the more bespoke your requirements are.